# how to find specific words in two marks?

Tags: python, regex

Hi I want to find specific word in certain pattenrs

like; I want to buy《tesla》 ->return : ['tesla ']

I tried to use 're' model in python, but I got only '《' again and again

how can I get 'tesla' in string?

I used findall module in re, but I could not get result.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `re.findall` this way:

```
re.findall(r'《([^《*.》]*)》',s)
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> s='I want to buy《tesla》'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'《([^《*.》]*)》',s)
['tesla']
>>>
```